# How do you make easy money in Assassin's Creed 4?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I want to ask how can I make easy money in Assassin's Creed 4 because the ship upgrade costs too much money and naval combat ships are crazy against powerful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found most of my money comes from naval warfare, but if that is too difficult for you, do treasure hunts with your maps or find chests.

Don't go into any naval battle against groups, even if your ship is well upgraded. fighting a bunch of Man'o'Wars is still gonna hurt.. you are only a glorified brig after all.

Always ALWAYS board ships, not only can you fix your ship up afterwards (or clean your wanted slate), but you only get half of the prize if you sink your enemy.

Something I recently learned and beat myself up over for not doing sooner is use your swivels every possible chance. I don't know what console your using, but on PC I didn't even know how to use the swivels until late in the game (holding the button wouldnt shoot them, and firing shot heavy shot instead of the swivel). It's simply just hold and release once it locks on... Upgrade them to the max level, and all you have to do is hold down the button to melt down every crit point and do a lot of damage.

If you go to taverns and "pay for information" or whatever it is, sometimes they will tell you the whereabouts of a naval convoy. the main ship on those is worth quite a bit of reales, so go for them any time you feel comfortable.

Sell resources you dont use. Cloth has very little use once you upgrade your storage areas and get the sail you want... so just start selling any extra you get. Whaling/hunting is also a quick relatively easy few hundred reales.

Comment: I will usually fight a man o'war with a low-level schooner or frigate nearby. I can take them out in a single volley of heavy shot + swivel guns. After the man o'war has been damaged significantly, and the jackdaw has been damaged significantly I will board the smaller ship just to get the repairs for the Jackdaw.

Answer (score 1):

I got 400k realles

It's really easy. In short kenway fleet. Clear a section. Send man of war you capture there.

In fact, all other money generating techniques are almost useless.

I can easily make 1 million realles if I am more determined.

The thing with kenway fleet is you have to wait a few days till the ships arrive. So yes, the high paying missions are those that take 2 days or 3 days to complete and not coming back.

So what?

I am not a hard core gamer. I am not in it when the ships make money.

Comment: I have 15 lvl 60 man of war. Once every 2-3 days I pick some far location and send all those fleet. Come back with $30k I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just attack convoys or low level ships until your wanted level is maxed out. Then fast travel to a naval fort you’ve clammed; then just go back and forth in front of it until the pirate hunters come. Then sit back and watch your fort render them immobile. Then come and take the loot; they typical have about 200 metal wood and cloth for man-o-wars and about 100-150 metal/wood/cloth for frigates. Or attack ships near a fort you’ve calmed and have them chase you until it repeats.

Answer (score -1):

there is a easy way to make money in AC4. In sequence 2 ,there is a mission called 'Mister Walpole I presume'. In that,The three templers Torres,Rogers and julienne will talk for a few minutes. There will a optional objective to loot the three templres. If you loot them , you will get above 250-300 reales. Totally you will get approximately 600 reales. Restart from last checkpoint and do it again and again. It will take really a lot of time, but if you want to get reales without any difficulties, then this is the best thing. I did that and got really a lot and lot of money, which is enough to upgrade the jackdaw and edward fully.

Answer (score -1):

In my own playthroughs of AC4 I normally hunt treasure chests down. In part because I always aimed for 100% sync anyway (and I achieved on my most recent one at last) but also because once you unlock the entire map you can actually gather a LOT of chests. What I remember from my last playthrough is that I had gained enough money to buy the strongest swords and guns pretty much as soon as the entire map unlocked and aside from ship upgrades (which also require materials from naval combat anyway) that meant I was pretty much set for the entire game.